# Weblogic Console Produce JMS Message Permissions

Tags: permissions, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

In the first picture, i access with admin user to "Produce JMS Message" on a JMS Queue of a JMS module, in this case the fields are available.

[image: Good Produce JMS Message]

In the next picture, i access with a Operator user to "Produce JMS Message" but the fields are unavailable.

[image: Bad Produce JMS Message]

What permissions and how i can add to the group or role for activate this fields?

Comment: You probably need to go to your Queue->Security->Policies and add the Operator group to Send.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work